# working with window orientation to fix ipad zooming issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, screen-rotation

So I'm sure you're familiar with a little issue that ipad has when rotating. When a user rotates the ipad wants to keep the initial scale and ends up zooming in when it rerenders.

A lot of people have suggested remedying it with this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

which works great except it doesn't allow the user to zoom in and out of the website anymore. I'm curious if there is a way to detect the orientation change swap the viewport information and then reset.

For example

on load my viewport would be

```
<meta name="viewport" id="view-port" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
```

then theoretically have some js that does something like this:

```
  window.onorientationchange = function() {
    $("#view-port").attr("content", "width=device-width, maximum-scale = 1.0, initial-    scale= 1.0");
    setTimeout("resetMetaTag()", 500);
 };

  var resetMetaTag = function() {
    $("#view-port").attr("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale= 1.0");
    console.log($("#view-port").attr("content"));
  };
```

This doesn't work because rather than swapping viewports before the orientation is made it does it asynchronously. Is there a way to detect a sort of "about to rotate" or to just interject a function prior to the screen being rerendered?

that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple answers here, to allow the user to zoom in and out add `user-scalable=1` to the viewport properties and remove `maximum-scale=1.0`, or change it to a higher value. `maximum-scale=1.0` means exactly that, the user will not be able to scale the screen any greater than its current level:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;" />
```

If you want to detect orientation change, attach an event listener to the window:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', updateOrientation, false);
```

In the updateOrientation function you can detect which orientation the device is in and reset the viewport attributes accordingly:

```
function updateOrientation() {
  if (!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) && !(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    return;
  }

  var viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");

  switch (window.orientation) {
    case 0: //portrait
      //set the viewport attributes to whatever you want!
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;');
      break;
    case 90: case -90: //landscape
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;');
      break;
    default:
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=1;');
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand that. I guess what I'm wondering is can I reset the initial zoom on a rotate event, I understand how to listen for the rotate event, but I want to reset initial zoom.

Comment: my answer illustrates how... when you switch orientation you can set the attributes of the viewport. whatever your initial zoom was, just set it again there.

Comment: I see that, but my question is asking how to disable the scaling and re-enable it after the rotation has happened. I don't want the zoom in but I also do not want the user to be unable to zoom in and out.

Comment: I see I'm going to have to break this down... set the initial scale to 1.0 when the document loads, when the orientation changes -> set the scale to 1.0 again.

Comment: exactly i need it to reset, however I dont' think the scale is being effected because it's still 1:1 on the rotate event.  I have an object that 100% of the window size, and when I do a console.log(obj.width() + " " + $(window).width()) I get a 1024 1024 response... meaning that I need to reset the zoom to 1 or 0 depending on what the default is.

Comment: also that didn't seem to work, resetting the initial-scale back to 1.0 didn't do anything.

Comment: I found that resetting it back to 1.0 scale doesn't do much for landscape because the default scale is a little larger. With my tests, 0.8 scale and slightly smaller text works best for landscape.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but in a sense wouldn't this be a little bit of a hack in the sense that you're shrinking the size on rotate? I mean it makes sense, I just need to justify my decision when my manager takes a look at it.

Comment: yes it is definitely a workaround, welcome to web programming! :P This issue only seems to persist on Apple devices though, iPod and iPhone specifically with the tests I performed. I've updated the code sample above to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

try this works for me:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-height, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=1;">
```

now when you rotate ipad it detects the right scale.